# Use NN Model in Unity with Barracuda

Tags: c#, tensorflow, unity-game-engine, machine-learning

I have a NN Model in the ONNX Format that I want to use in Unity. An older version of the model worked fine but after we updated the model and changed the models input I'm no longer able to integrate it.

The previous model would take 60 float values, in the inspector the input looked like this:
**dense_input** shape(n:*, h:1, w:1, c:60)

I got that model working with the following code

```cs
public NNModel modelAsset;
private IWorker worker;
private Tensor input = new Tensor(1, 60);

private void Start() {
    var model = ModelLoader.Load(modelAsset);
    worker = WorkerFactory.CreateWorker(WorkerFactory.Type.ComputePrecompiled, model);
}

public int RunModel(Vector3[] pointCloud) {
    // pointCloud has 20 values -> 60 floats. Use each float as an input
    for (int i = 0; i < pointCloud.Length;i++) {
        int startIndex = i * 3;
        input[startIndex] = pointCloud[i].x;
        input[startIndex + 1] = pointCloud[i].y;
        input[startIndex + 2] = pointCloud[i].z;
    }

    // Run model
    worker.Execute(input);
    // ...
}
```

The updated model instead takes 20 float arrays of size 3. In the inspector is looks like this:
**input_13** shape(n:*, h:1, w:3, c:20)

my naive approach was to change the input Tensor to

```cs
private Tensor input = new Tensor(3, 20);
```

or

```cs
private Tensor input = new Tensor(1, 1, 3, 20);
```

According to the documentation, one can access the tensor input like this
`tensor4D[n, h, w, c] = 1.0f;`
Therefore I updated my code to

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < pointCloud.Length; i++) {
        input[0, 0, 0, i] = pointCloud[i].x;
        input[0, 0, 1, i] = pointCloud[i].y;
        input[0, 0, 2, i] = pointCloud[i].z;
}
```

If I run the code I receive an AssertionError on the line where I call worker.Execute(input);

> AssertionException: Assertion failure. Values are not equal.
> Expected: 3 == 20

I tried various things to "fill" the input Tensor but I just can't wrap my head around it. This is currently the most promising solution but I still fail to make it work. Most of my other attempts caused an OutOfBounds Exception during the loop.

I'm using Barracuda 3.0 (Unity LTS 2021.3.19f)

Comment: Hi there, were you able to find a solution? I'm facing the same issue

Answer (score 1):

I tried to add a comment, but my reputation was not enough.

> dense_input shape(n:*, h:1, w:1, c:60)

h refers to height,
w refers to width,
c refers to channel (for example rgb, 3 channel)
[Model Execution](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.barracuda@3.0/manual/ModelExecution.html)

> AssertionException: Assertion failure. Values are not equal. Expected: 3 == 20

As far as I understand from the error, you need to change the dimensions and channel values.
So try with

```
private Tensor input = new Tensor(1, 1, 20, 3);  // 20 for width and 3 for channel
```

and fill the tensor like

```
for (int i = 0; i < pointCloud.Length; i++) {
    input[0, 0, i, 0] = pointCloud[i].x;
    input[0, 0, i, 1] = pointCloud[i].y;
    input[0, 0, i, 2] = pointCloud[i].z;
}
```

Your model may be showing mixed input values(may have been corrupted during model conversion).
I am using the [netron](https://github.com/lutzroeder/netron) application to view the input outputs of the models. Maybe it can help you.

or

Barracuda may have changed the input order of your model.
In the [barracuda](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.barracuda@3.0/manual/TensorHandling.html) documentation:

> Note: The native ONNX data layout is channels-first. Barracuda automatically converts ONNX models to channel-last layout.